# Convert mm-dd-yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I change the format of a date in my report from `mm-dd-yyyy` to `dd-mm-yyyy`. When I attempt this, I get an error saying I'm missing a parenthesis.

```
If Right(Left(ToText(Month(Date({BAQReportParameter.Option01})),2,1))="-" Then 
    ("0"+Left(Left(ToText(Month(Date({BAQReportParameter.Option01}),2)),1))+"-"
    +Left(ToText(Year(Date({BAQReportParameter.Option01})),1)
    +Mid((ToText(Year(Date({BAQReportParameter.Option01})))),3,3) 

Else(Left(ToText(Month(Date({BAQReportParameter.Option01}))),2)+"-"
    +Left(ToText(Year(Date({BAQReportParameter.Option01})),1)
    +Mid((ToText(Year(Date({BAQReportParameter.Option01}))),3,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a lengthy process instead you can try below:

```
ToText({BAQReportParameter.Option01},"dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: The error is: "Foram fornecidos argumentos em excesso para esta função".

Comment: is this `{BAQReportParameter.Option01}` date database field or normal string field with date data?

Answer (score 0):

If Option01 is a **String**:

```
ToText(DateValue({BAQReportParameter.Option01}),"dd-MM-yyyy")
```

---

If Option01 is a **Date**, Right Click it, go to *Format*, and click *Customize*:

[image]